# how to change value dynamically variable

Tags: dotless

how to use dynamically dotless variables. I mean how to assign value dynamically in dotless file. Is there any way?

style.less file contain

```
@url_image: 

#head{ background: url(@url_image) no-repeat left top white;}
```

How can I assign a value at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say change dynamically in .less file, I am not sure why you wanna just change it in less file. If you just change it in .less file, you'll have to compile the file in order to navigative the change to style.min.css and style.css files, which you can't do programmatically.

This is what you can do:

```
 $('#head').css('background-image', "url("new-source");
```

So jquery/javascript is your best bet

Comment: can we use here parsing method. if can then how to do? please provide me assistance.

Comment: What do you mean by parsing method ? What do you wanna parse ? Please clarify, happy to help.

Comment: yes parse. thanks. how can we do with parse ? actually this is requirement.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are asking...can you give an example ?

Comment: can i parse some parameters values in .less file are any other alternative way will be acceptable to make it dynamic. actually i have database i want to change colors value according to the users how can i do this.

Comment: No, you cannot pass parameters to .less files. Your best bet is to use jquery or any server-language and overwrite the background

Comment: can we overwrite existing css with the server language then how can we?

Comment: @sumeshgaud & Ani You are not talking about the same thing. Sumesh is talking about dotless and not less.js. jQuery is not helping him in any way as he is trying to manipulate variables being parsed serverside.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this.  In my case, both the less content and dynamic parameters are stored in the DB.  You can do something like this if you want to change a hex code color for example:

```
var parser = new dotless.Core.Parser.Parser();
var env = new dotless.Core.Parser.Infrastructure.Env { Compress = true, Debug = true, KeepFirstSpecialComment = false, DisableVariableRedefines = false };
var tree = parser.Parse(css.Detail.Text, null);

foreach (var key in layout.LessDetails.CurrentValues.Keys)
{
   var rule = tree.Variable("@" + key, tree);

   if (rule != null)
   {
      string value = layout.LessDetails.CurrentValues[key];

      if (value != null && value.StartsWith("#"))
      {
         rule.Value = new dotless.Core.Parser.Tree.Color(value.TrimStart('#'));
      }
   }
}

css.Detail.GeneratedText = tree.ToCSS(env);
```

This isn't an end all solution since there are many other types of parameters, but it should lead you in the right direction.  Look in the dotless.Core.Parser.Functions for useful information on the various options.

Alternatively, there is another simple option.  With the code above, you can simply append the changed variables to the end of the css.Detail.Text string.  This is actually how the modifyVars method works in the less.js file.  By adding the parameters again at the end, it overrides the previous set values.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done if you manually parse and output the dotless file.

```
var config = DotlessConfiguration.GetDefaultWeb();
config.DisableVariableRedefines = true;

string less = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(less);
sb.AppendLine(string.Format("{0}: {1};", "@url_image", "image.jpg"));

return LessWeb.Parse(sb.ToString(), config);
```